# Mysql fulltext index search returning weird result

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have ingredient table. I want all those recipes which have certain ingredients. Below is my table structure.

```
Table(ingredient) - Applied fulltext index on ingredient column.
------------------------------------------------------
 ingredientID   rcteID  ingredient  
    310           1     Mint Leaves     
    311           1     Corriender Leaves   
    312           1     GreenChili
```

I am trying to fetch above record below fulltext search query but not getting that record.

```
SELECT `Ingredient`.`ingredientID` , `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
FROM `ingredient` AS `Ingredient`
WHERE MATCH (`Ingredient`.`ingredient`) 
      AGAINST ('+Mint Leaves +Corriender Leaves +Greenchili' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
IN ( 1 )
GROUP BY `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
```

Why above query is not working for above record?

**When I tried below query it worked. just changed searching text.**

```
SELECT `Ingredient`.`ingredientID` , `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
FROM `ingredient` AS `Ingredient`
WHERE MATCH (`Ingredient`.`ingredient`) 
      AGAINST ('+Greenchili +Mint Leaves +Corriender Leaves' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
IN ( 1 )
GROUP BY `Ingredient`.`rcteID`

OUTPUT
--------------------
ingredientID    rcteID
311               1
```

Don't understand what's going on. Why first query not returning any result and below query returning result?

Comment: So which records from those 3 you want returned with the first query and which records it actually returns?

Comment: just edited my question. you can see output I got.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an real explanation, but you can run this query to see the score.

```
SELECT MATCH (`Ingredient`.`ingredient`) 
      AGAINST ('+Mint Leaves +Corriender Leaves +Greenchili' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
FROM `ingredient` AS `Ingredient`
WHERE MATCH (`Ingredient`.`ingredient`) 
      AGAINST ('+Mint Leaves +Corriender Leaves +Greenchili' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I believe that your query mean: find ingredients that each of them contains **ALL** of these *Mint Leaves, Corriender Leaves, Greenchili*, and which is not found in your data set. MySQL cannot find any row that contains all of these keywords above.

However if you but your query into brackets, it is a different story:

```
SELECT `Ingredient`.`ingredientID` , `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
FROM `ingredient` AS `Ingredient`
WHERE MATCH (`Ingredient`.`ingredient`) 
      AGAINST ('(+Greenchili) (+Mint Leaves) (+Corriender Leaves)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
IN ( 1 )
GROUP BY `Ingredient`.`rcteID`
```

This query can be translated into: Fetch me ingredients which contains **AT LEAST one of these**:*Mint Leaves, Corriender Leaves, Greenchili* and group them by rcteID.

UPDATED:

```
SELECT t1.rcteID FROM `ingredient` t1
    JOIN `ingredient` t2 ON t2.rcteID = t1.rcteID
    JOIN `ingredient` t3 ON t3.rcteID = t2.rcteID
WHERE 
    MATCH (t1.`ingredient`) AGAINST ('+Greenchili' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND
    MATCH (t2.`ingredient`) AGAINST ('+Mint Leaves' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND 
    MATCH (t3.`ingredient`) AGAINST ('+Corriender Leaves' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND t1.`rcteID` IN ( 1 )
GROUP BY t1.`rcteID`
```

I think this query will work for you. Basically, it share the same idea with you but it looks for 3 keywords separately and only get the rcteID which contains 3 ingredients.

Comment: I want those rcteID which contains all these 3 ingredient not at least one. Can you guide me how can I write that query?

Comment: Seems, this is not effective way because we need to join the table as much as times as my keywords.